# Existence of a specific invertible matrix

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am an homework question from course in linear algebra, which I don't know how to solve.
I need to know if $\exists A_3$, A is a invertible matrix that holds $A^2=-I_3$ , when I is the identity matrix.
I tried to do some algebra manipulation but unsuccesfully.

This claim is true or false? why>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the determinant we get
$$\det(A^2)=(\det(A))^2=\det(-I_3)=-1$$
which is impossible if we assume that the given matrix is over $\Bbb R$.

Notice that over $\Bbb C$ we can take $A=\operatorname{diag}(i,i,i)$ and then $A^2=-I_3$.

Comment: Sorry. I edited the question. the order need to be 3. have any idea?